# audio element loops before the end

Tags: html, html5-audio

Whever I set

```
s.loop = true
```

or with onended event :

```
s.onended = function()
{
    this.currentTime = 0 ;
    this.play();
};
```

it loops a few seconds before the end of the track....

Did anybody here experienced this problem before and found how to fix it ?

(Yes I know webaudio is way better, but it takes ages to decode files on mobiles, so I use it only for short sounds and have to use the nasty old audio element for music.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to always repeat the audio, and it does not work through Javascript, you can use loop tag in HTML

```
<audio controls loop>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

> I test your code and play complete sound, then repeat the sound

```
<audio id="Audio" controls>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
   </audio>

<script>
   var s = document.getElementById("Audio");
       s.loop = true;
   </script>

<script>
       var s = document.getElementById("Audio");
           s.onended = function(){
           this.currentTime = 0 ;
           this.play();
        }
       </script>
```